# Publishing WCF metadata operation contract parameters

Tags: wcf, metadata

The wsdl for my WCF service does not list the input parameters for the operations.

I'm doing http://localhost:123/CalculatorService.svc?wsdl. The browser displays the wsdl but as I said no input parameters.

I've looked high and low. I've found a lot of examples of how to enable wsdl generation but nothing that talks explicitly about the input parameters.

WcfTestClient gets the input parameters so I know they are available somehow.

Here's a section of my Web.config & app.Config (I changed names for privacy purposes).

```
 <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy15" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>

    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy15"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <service
      name="MyServiceNamespace.CalculatorService"
      behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceNamespaceBehavior">

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:63906/CalculatorService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

    <endpoint address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="MyServiceNamespace.CalculatorService" />

    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 1):

The wsdl generated by WCF includes namespaces, and some of the namespaces link to schema documents that define the input and output contracts. That's where the method arguments are described.